# Finding 1911 marriage record from Poland

Tags: marriage-records, poland, 1910s

My grandfather Stanislaw Czyzyk  was born 23 May 1885 at Kurpiecz or Grodno.

My grandmother Julia Zinkowski was born 19 Mar 1896 in Czernawta (as far as I could find in old records, or Bialystok which I grew up being told).

They were married on 23 Jun 1911 in Kurpiecz.

Where can I find a record of that marriage?

Comment: If answers to finding their marriage record don’t lead you to their birth/baptism records then feel free to ask separate questions about finding those.

Comment: Where have you looked already? If there are no databases or microfilms for that time & place, that would be good to mention.  If any such thing does exist, but doesn't appear to include your grandparents' record, that would also be useful information. Were ledger books kept for such things? If so, where would they be now? I can't tell if this is a question about Polish marriage records in general, or if it's specific to this one couple.

Comment: I was able to locate my father's birth certificate and found his mother's name is Julia Zajaczkowska and father is Stanislaw Czyzyk, both born in Russia.  Also found great grandfather name Luzat (Luzaf?) Czyzyk. Looking for any info on my grandparents.